# Embedded Linux Framebuffer Rotate in software

Tags: linux, rotation, embedded, framebuffer

On my embedded system (AT91SAM9G45) I have to rotate the display by 90 degrees. But the problem is the AT91SAM9G45 can't do this in hardware. So I must try it to rotate with a software solution.

I searched a lot but I did not found a solution for how to do this.

I use buildroot 2014-03 and a modified AT91SAM9M10G45-EK board. The display is OK, because with fbcon I am able to rotate the console. But my GUI applications run with Qt. So if I start a Qt5 application the GUI is wrong. It is in portrait mode I need landscape mode.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: please specify better what you have already tried, which linux do you use and so on

Comment: I use buildroot 2014-03 and a modified AT91SAM9M10G45-EK board. The display is OK, because with fbcon I am able to rotate the console. But my GUI applications run with Qt. So if I start a Qt5 application the GUI is wrong. It is in portrait mode I need landscape mode.

Comment: edit your question above directly and add this information.

Comment: @flomll, Did you resolve this issue with Qt rotate ?  how ?